# Which hook is invoked when an order is updated?

Tags: hooks, commerce

Which hook is invoked when an order is updated?

I created a module that must perform some operations when an order is modified, for example when its status is changed or when an item is changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commerce doesn't provide an explicit hook for that ([these are the hooks it does define for orders](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order.api.php/DC)).

Since a commerce order is an entity, you're looking for [`hook_entity_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/7), which is used to

> Act on entities when inserted.

Comment: thanks. I am working on it. My issue is do some operations when an entity with type "commerce_order" is updated. so I used "hook_entity_update" and in my function I used this condition if($type == 'commerce_order') {}

Answer (score 7):

The documentation for [commerce_order_status_update()](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order.module/function/commerce_order_status_update/DC) says:

> While there is no explicit Rules event or hook devoted to an order
>   status being updated...

It is possible to use [hook_commerce_order_presave()](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order.api.php/function/hook_commerce_order_presave/DC):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_order_presave().
 */
function my_module_commerce_order_presave($order) {
  if ($order->status != $order->original->status) {
    drupal_set_message("The order status changed from {$order->original->status} to {$order->status}");
  }
}
```

Here's an optional helper function for use elsewhere if you have an `$order` object, and are curious if its status has changed from what is stored in the database:

```
/**
 * Given an order object, this returns FALSE if the order status has not
 * changed. If it has changed, it returns an associative array with the
 * following keys: new_order_status, old_order_status
 */
function my_module_order_status_changed($order) {
  $result['new_order_status'] = $order->status;
  $result['old_order_status'] = db_select('commerce_order', 'co')
    ->fields('co', array('status'))
    ->condition('co.order_id', $order->order_id)
    ->execute()
    ->fetchField();
  if ($result['new_order_status'] == $result['old_order_status']) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Where did you pull out hook_order_status_changed. Doesnt work and I dont see anywhere hook_order_status_changed  documented?

Comment: The hook is `hook_commerce_order_presave()` with the boolean outlined above. There is no hook called `hook_order_status_changed()`, that is just a helper function I've created.

Answer (score 1):

Try: hook_commerce_order_presave($order);

It allows you to prepare order data before it is saved.

Comment: can you provide some example code?